# grpc unsolicited message from server?

Tags: events, server, grpc

is it possible to create server based unsolicited "events", "messages"
(e.g. message that is NOT a reply to a client's request, but generated
on behalf of the server) in gRPC?
[Tried googling for it, but couldn't find any relevant answer, mind me]
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the server to initiate the connection from the server and send a message with no prior interaction from the client, then no, you can't do that with gRPC.

However, this fits perfectly into the "subscriber" pattern that gRPC is intended to support: the client opens a server-streaming request (possibly indicating which messages or events they would like to receive), then the server responds with each message or event as it appears.

Comment: Well it is not mandatory that the server opens up the unsolicited connection to the client. The client could open two "sockets" to the server. The sole requirement is really to be able to send messages on this unsolicited socket from the server to the client without any kind of initial communication from the client, but as i understand the subscriber concept is exactly that

Comment: As i checked gRPC, server side streaming also requires a request to be sent first from the client, based upon which the server starts the streaming. Or?

Comment: Yes, server streaming requires the client to send a single initial message. The client already sends a little information to initiate the call; it should not matter if they also have to send a single message. But if that really matters, you can use a duplex stream and have the client send nothing.

Comment: Also you have to consider, that the server needs some sort of connection info from the client anyway: e.g. which IP address to use or the hostname, if available. This burden is taken away if the client makes the request and the server streams back responses.